# using loops to read excel data, assign to dynamic variable and display on tkinter gui using dynamic labels

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

To reduce my current coding lines, I want to use loops to read excel data in range C49:C59 and want to assign each cell value to a dynamic variable. Then I want to make labels with names dynamically made from the loop counter and then use those variables as textvariable (to assign values to labels) and then finally use the labels in my tkinter gui.

Can you simplify the coding using loops?

Here is my current code using too many lines.

```
wb100 = xw.Book("Data.xlsm")
ws101 = wb100.sheets("Differential Pressure")

dpc49 = IntVar()
dpc50 = IntVar()
dpc51 = IntVar()
dpc52 = IntVar()
dpc53 = IntVar()
dpc54 = IntVar()
dpc55 = IntVar()
dpc56 = IntVar()
dpc57 = IntVar()
dpc58 = IntVar()
dpc59 = IntVar()

dpc49.set(ws101.range("C49").value)
dpc50.set(ws101.range("C50").value)
dpc51.set(ws101.range("C51").value)
dpc52.set(ws101.range("C52").value)
dpc53.set(ws101.range("C53").value)
dpc54.set(ws101.range("C54").value)
dpc55.set(ws101.range("C55").value)
dpc56.set(ws101.range("C56").value)
dpc57.set(ws101.range("C57").value)
dpc58.set(ws101.range("C58").value)
dpc59.set(ws101.range("C59").value)

lab_dpc49 = Label(frame_100, textvariable=dpc49,justify=CENTER,width=14,bg="#2E2E2E",pady=2,background="yellow",fg=nlcolor,font='Arial 8')
lab_dpc50 = Label(frame_100, textvariable=dpc50,justify=CENTER,width=14,bg="#2E2E2E",pady=2,background="yellow",fg=nlcolor,font='Arial 8')
lab_dpc51 = Label(frame_100, textvariable=dpc51,justify=CENTER,width=14,bg="#2E2E2E",pady=2,background="yellow",fg=nlcolor,font='Arial 8')
lab_dpc52 = Label(frame_100, textvariable=dpc52,justify=CENTER,width=14,bg="#2E2E2E",pady=2,background="yellow",fg=nlcolor,font='Arial 8')
lab_dpc53 = Label(frame_100, textvariable=dpc53,justify=CENTER,width=14,bg="#2E2E2E",pady=2,background="yellow",fg=nlcolor,font='Arial 8')
lab_dpc54 = Label(frame_100, textvariable=dpc54,justify=CENTER,width=14,bg="#2E2E2E",pady=2,background="yellow",fg=nlcolor,font='Arial 8')
lab_dpc55 = Label(frame_100, textvariable=dpc55,justify=CENTER,width=14,bg="#2E2E2E",pady=2,background="yellow",fg=nlcolor,font='Arial 8')
lab_dpc56 = Label(frame_100, textvariable=dpc56,justify=CENTER,width=14,bg="#2E2E2E",pady=2,background="yellow",fg=nlcolor,font='Arial 8')
lab_dpc57 = Label(frame_100, textvariable=dpc57,justify=CENTER,width=14,bg="#2E2E2E",pady=2,background="yellow",fg=nlcolor,font='Arial 8')
lab_dpc58 = Label(frame_100, textvariable=dpc58,justify=CENTER,width=14,bg="#2E2E2E",pady=2,background="yellow",fg=nlcolor,font='Arial 8')
lab_dpc59 = Label(frame_100, textvariable=dpc59,justify=CENTER,width=14,bg="#2E2E2E",pady=2,background="yellow",fg=nlcolor,font='Arial 8')

lab_dpc49.grid(row=2, column=2)
lab_dpc50.grid(row=3, column=2)
lab_dpc51.grid(row=4, column=2)
lab_dpc52.grid(row=5, column=2)
lab_dpc53.grid(row=6, column=2)
lab_dpc54.grid(row=7, column=2)
lab_dpc55.grid(row=8, column=2)
lab_dpc56.grid(row=9, column=2)
lab_dpc57.grid(row=10, column=2)
lab_dpc58.grid(row=11, column=2)
lab_dpc59.grid(row=12, column=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you have a sequence of variables that have numbers in them, the simple solution is to move them into a dictionary. Something like this, for example:

```
vars = {}
labels = {}
row = 2
for i in range(49, 60):
    value = ws101.range(f"C{i}").value
    vars[i] = IntVar(value=value)
    labels[i] = Label(frame_100, textvariable=vars[i], ...)
    labels[i].grid(row=row, ...)
    row += 1
```